# Set number of rounds in a tournament conditionally (OOP, python)

Tags: python, django, oop

Part of the reason why I'm asking this question is because I don't know what the proper way to ask this question is. I'm trying to create a calculator for Swiss-style tournaments in Django. Tournaments may have different numbers of rounds, so I need to be able to access the score for each round. Here is my model for a single participant in the tournament:

```
class Speaker(models.Model):
    speaker = models.CharField(max_length = 32)
    team_name = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    tournaName = models.CharField(max_length = 32) 
    round1 = models.IntegerField()
    round2 = models.IntegerField()
    round3 = models.IntegerField()
    round4 = models.IntegerField() #what if I only wanted three rounds? or five?
    totalScores = models.IntegerField()

    def updateTotals(self):
        self.totalScores = self.round1 + self.round2 + self.round3 + self.round4
```

Basically, I want to be able to make as many or as little "round" variables as I want. Is there a way to do what I want or should I be rethinking how I'm structuring my models?

Comment: Why not just make a `Round` model that you can have a 1-M relationship with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one approach to the problem

Create a RoundScore models where you store the score for each round, player and tournament.

```
class RoundScore:
    player = ForeignKey(Player) # ref to the player
    tournament = ForeignKey(Tournament) # ref to the tournament
    round = Integer() # the round number
    score = Integer() # the score for this round
```

then have a models for player and tournament where you store informations about them.

With this solution you can have any numbers of round for each tournament without problems and you can retrieve the score for each player by round and sum all the score round for one player in a tournament.